# Listview does not update the UI when an Item changes

Tags: listview, observablecollection

I have an annoying problem that I have been struggling with for hours.
I have a simple Listview application on which I want to change the customer name by typing a new name and sending it via button click.
The listview looks fine and I see in the code behind (debug) that the value for new names changes but my cursed lisview keeps the old name.

````
namespace WpfTurtorial
{
    public class DemoCustomer: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public DemoCustomer SelectedCustomer { get; set; }


      
            private int idValue;
            private string customerNameValue = String.Empty;
            private string phoneNumberValue = String.Empty;
            public string newCustName = String.Empty;

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }


            /*
            private DemoCustomer()
            {
                customerNameValue = "Customer";
                phoneNumberValue = "(312)555-0100";
            }

            public static DemoCustomer CreateNewCustomer()
            {
                return new DemoCustomer();
            }
            */




            public int ID
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.idValue;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.idValue = value;
                }
            }

            public string CustomerName
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.customerNameValue;
                }

                set
                {

                    if (value != this.customerNameValue)
                    {
                        this.customerNameValue = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    }


                }
            }

            public string PhoneNumber
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.phoneNumberValue;
                }

                set
                {
                    if (value != this.phoneNumberValue)
                    {
                        this.phoneNumberValue = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            public string NewCustName
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.newCustName;
                }

                set
                {
                    if (value != this.newCustName)
                    {
                        this.newCustName = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

    }


}

`



```
namespace WpfTurtorial
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private ObservableCollection<DemoCustomer> _items;
        public ObservableCollection<DemoCustomer> Items
        {
            get
            {
                if (_items == null)
                {
                    _items = new ObservableCollection<DemoCustomer>();
                }
                return _items;
            }
            set
            {
                _items = value;
               
            }
        }


        private ICommand _command;

        public DemoCustomer SelectedCustomer { get; set; }


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            ChangeCustomer();

        }


     

        private void ChangeCustomer()
        {

            Items = new ObservableCollection<DemoCustomer>
            {
                new DemoCustomer { ID = 1234, CustomerName = "Customer1", PhoneNumber = "1234-9876543", NewCustName = "" },
                new DemoCustomer { ID = 1235, CustomerName = "Customer2", PhoneNumber = "1234-9876544", NewCustName = "" }
            };
        
        }


        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return _command ?? (_command = new RelayCommand(x => { SetCustomerName(x.ToString()); })); }
        }

        private static void SetCustomerName(string names)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Responding to click event on " + names);
            DemoCustomer demo = new DemoCustomer();
            
            demo.CustomerName = names;

        }

        private void ListView1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView1.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTurtorial.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTurtorial"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>


        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="199*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="18*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="ListView1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}" Loaded="ListView1_Loaded">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="ID" Header="ID" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="CustomerName" Header="CustomerName" Width="230" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomerName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="PhoneNumber" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber}" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="NewName" Header="New Name" Width="230">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbCustName" Width="200" Text="{Binding Path=NewCustName}"></TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="btn1" Header="Set" Width="130">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Width="80" Height="22" Margin="1" 
                                Command="{Binding ElementName=ListView1, Path=DataContext.Command}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=NewCustName}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Change Name" />
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>


                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
`




I have tried all forms of dependencies to update the listview. All forms of help are gratefully received
````

Comment: I have solved the problem and will shortly upload the solution so that more people can share. I see many threads on the internet, e.g. in this forum that dealt with this topic. I think many people, including me, have had problems updating the view when one or more items are changed.